# Testing getLocaleFirstDayOfWeek

Tags: angular, unit-testing, date, locale

Swedish week starts on Monday. Used `getLocaleFirstDayOfWeek` to fetch the first day of the week. When testing, it kept providing Sunday as the first day of the week. It required the test to register the local data to work correctly. Is this a defect or as expected?

```js
import { getLocaleFirstDayOfWeek, registerLocaleData, WeekDay } from '@angular/common';
import EN_SE from '@angular/common/locales/en-SE';

describe('getLocaleFirstDayOfWeek', () => {
  beforeAll(() => registerLocaleData(EN_SE, 'en-SE'));

  fit('should start the week on monday', () => {
    const firstDayOfWeek = getLocaleFirstDayOfWeek('en-SE');
    expect(firstDayOfWeek).toEqual(WeekDay.Monday);
  });
});
```

Comment: You should not test any native functionality of angular or any other package. It's already tested (or should be) by it own test suite.

Comment: I am not testing the angular function. Testing an implementation using this function, and it fails if the local is registered. When running the application, we don't have to register the locale data. In the case of the test, we had to register the local data to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay found the answer! With Angular 5 onwards only the `en-US` is included by default, any additional locales need to be registered via `registerLocaleData`.

> By default Angular now only contains locale data for the language en-US, if you set the value of LOCALE_ID to another locale, you will have to import new locale data for this language because we don’t use the intl API anymore.